# Fazer logging de um arquivo batch

Tags: batch, powershell, agendamento

Eu estou com o seguinte problema:

Recebemos diariamente um backup do banco de dados das 4AM às 5AM, e temos um batch job executando às 6 AM para colocar esse banco rodando numa VM.

No Agendador de tarefas, está tudo ok, e ele executa todos os dias, porém queremos ter um log das ações que o arquivo batch faz.

Existe algum modo de fazer isso?

O que já tentei:

1. Chamar o batch com um outro batch que grava o output em um arquivo. O agendador faz a tarefa rodar indefinidamente.
2. Chamar um script de powershell para executar o batch e gravar em um arquivo. Mesmo problema do acima
3. Rodear instruções do batch com `()` e com isso fazer ele imprimir os resultados das instruções. `>"arquivo" (instruções)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Adicione um **`if`** para um loop condicional

**2)** Redirecione uma chamada para o própio bat **"setando" o arquivo.log**.

**3)** **adicione** as 3 linhas/códigos abaixo e **no início** do seu arquivo **`.bat`** já **existente**.

---

> **Update**: Para também salvar no **mesmo log** os eventuais/possíveis **erros**
>
> - Mude:   **`"%~0" >>!_log! & exit /b`**
> - Para:   **`"%~0" >!_log! 2>&1 & exit /b`**

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
if /i "!_log!/" == "/" (echo/Chamada do lote iniciada: !date! - / - !time!
set _log="%temp%\log_bat.log" && echo/>!_log! & "%~0" >>!_log! & exit /b) else (endlocal)
:: seu código atual em bat começa nesse ponto salvando as saídas em "%temp%\log_bat.log” ::
```

---

> - comentando:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

rem :: verifica se a variável recebeu valor :: 
if /i "!_log!/" == "/" (

   echo/Chamada do lote iniciada: !date! - / - !time!

   rem :: caso não tenha recebido algum valor, vai atribuir e chamar o próprio bat 
   set _log="%temp%\log_bat.log" && echo/>!_log! & "%~0" >>!_log! & exit /b

   rem :: caso tenha recebido algum valor, vai seguir a execução do bat, já salvando em: !_log! 
   ) else (endlocal)

:: seu código atual em bat começa nesse ponto salvando as saídas em 
 %temp%\log_bat.log” ::
```

Comment: Acabou solucionando o problema! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Apenas complementando a resposta do amigo acima, na hora de salvar o log, se usar apenas (>), apaga os resultados já existentes no arquivo, com (>>) dois sinal de maior acrescenta as mensagens no final do arquivo, mantendo os registros já existentes.